# L298 overheating issue

Tags: pcb-design, h-bridge, l298

I'm trying to build a motor driver which can supply ~3A per motor. Only cheap IC I could get my hands on was [L298](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf), so I decided to parallel its channels.
But for some reason that I can't understand (I'm merely an amateur hobbyist), L298 and its diodes are getting too hot in just a matter of seconds.

I'm using a 12V (max 40W) power supply for my circuit, and its reduced to 0.95V when I check VCC/GND pins (how is that even possible ?)

This is my PCB design.

47uF capacitors,

1N5819 diodes,

[L298N](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf)

[image]

Edit:
Schematics
[image]

Comment: Can you please post your circuit schematic diagram? Not everyone will have the luxury of time understanding your issue by mapping PCB traces and pin connections.

Comment: I suspect you have a short somewhere, or one of your diodes is the wrong way round. Your silkscreen layer is a bit mangled and one of your labels is upside down..

Comment: What's a L298?  What's your circuit?  It should have been obvious that you need to link to the datasheet and provide a schematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't labelled + and - on your battery!

Assuming that battery pin 1 is positive, because it's connected to VS of the L298, then your diodes are the wrong way round in the schematic.

Edit: the 0.9V is exactly as expected, as that's the forward voltage of the diode. You're sinking the full current of your power supply through a diode and the L298.

Comment: Your PCB seems to contradict your circuit diagram in this all-important aspect. The PCB seems to be OK.